# Как добавить get параметр к url, в зависимости от языка сайта

Tags: php

Скорее всего решение на поверхности, но я уже много чего перепробовал и не получается. Нужно добавлять get параметр к url, если страница на английском языке. 
Вот мой код, который не работает:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2));
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if ($lang == "en") {
   $url .= '?flagclick=true';
}
```

По правде говоря сайт вообще из-за этого кода ловит 500-ю.

Comment: Причину 500-й обнаружил, лишняя скобка, но результат не изменился.

Comment: непонятно что вы хотите сделать с ?flagclick=true  ?, просто к $url добавьте языковый код( &lang=en ) и сделайте редирект

Comment: @Арсен Нужно именно ?flagclick=true добавлять. Если язык страницы английский, то добавляем к url, а если русский, то не добавляем

Comment: и.... после добавления flagclick вы делаете редирект с новыми параметрами URL?

Answer (score 1):

Окей, а так:

```
$lang = 'en';
$url = 'http://example.net/';

if ($lang == "en") {
   $url .= (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY) ? '&' : '?') . 'flagclick=true';
}
```

Comment: не пашет, добавляет к названию сайта еще одно его название+этот гет параметр, а если просто добавлять гет параметр, то ошибка, что много редиректов.

Answer (score 1):

```html
$lang = 'en';
$url = 'http://example.net/';

if ($lang == "en" && !isset($_GET['flagclick'])) { // Проверяем или язык английский и существует ли гет параметр
    echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh'; content='0; URL=". $url ."?flagclick=true'></head></html>"; // если условие истина то перезагружаем страницу с гет параметром
}
```

Comment: Я заменил $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
Редиректит на https://example.net/example.net/?flagclick=true

Comment: если не менять, то при переходе на другие страницы все время редиректит на ту, которая указана в переменной $url

Comment: Попробуйте `$url = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`. А что у вас выдает `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` и `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`?